# android ContextCompat.getColor cannot resolve method

Tags: android, android-context

Code:

```
backgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.TapBarMenu_tbm_backgroundColor, 
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red));
```

is red in editor for `getcolor` in `ContextCompat.getColor` - "cannot resolve method". The app compiles and runs. During debug when I evaluate expression `ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red)` before stepping over the above line app breaks with error "tried to execute code in unprepared class 'Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;'", if I step over the line, then after that evaluate expression works fine.

The question: how to get rid of error show in Android Studio editor as it's annoying. Also, does that error mean anything?

Comment: "cannot resolve method" -- make sure that you are using the latest edition of the Android Support libraries in your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
    // other stuff here
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
}
```

After adding this dependency it will properly work. As ContextCompat is added in support-v4 so it is compulsory to have it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting `import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;` and rebuilding got rid of error in Android Studio editor that re-added `import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;`.